# How does this Sparse Array work (AP CS 2015 Q3)

Tags: java

You get a class that represents a sparse array. It contains a list of SparseArrayEntry objects, each of which represents one of the non-zero elements in the array. The entries representing the non-zero elements are stored in the list in no particular order. Each non-zero element is represented by exactly one entry in the list.

Link to the problem from the 2015 test(has the visual aid):
https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/digitalServices/pdf/ap/ap15_frq_computer_science_a.pdf

## Answer:

```
public int getValueAt(int row, int col){
for ( SparseArrayEntry e : entries){
if(e.getRow() == row && e.getCol() == col){ 
return e.getValue(); // found the value
}
}
return 0; // no such value
```

What throws me off is how this array list is 2D. Is it that it is an array list of lists? How is this thing traversed?

Answer (score 0):

It is traversed by calling the the getRow() and getCol() methods(see page 14). The objects hold these positions individually as well as the value.